# Use the same method to add elements to ArrayList of String or other object

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, parameters

I, I would like to use the same method to add elements to `ArrayList` of `String` or `ArrayList` of other object. So the `ArrayList` is of one type but I can pass different arrayList to this method
The problem is the add method, how can I use this method to add `String` or FleetInfo (my object)?
If I use ArrayList treeFolders I have no error in this method but I can't pass ArrayList

```
private <T> void addStatisticalFiles (String fleetName, ArrayList<T> treeFolders, boolean isFleetInfo){
        String fleetPath = env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH) + fleetName + File.separator + "statistics";
        File statisticalFolder = new File(fleetPath);
        if (statisticalFolder != null && statisticalFolder.exists()){
            if (!isFleetInfo){
                treeFolders.add(fleetPath);
                for(String statisticalFile : statisticalFolder.list()){
                    treeFolders.add(fleetPath + File.separator + statisticalFile);
                }
            }else{
                treeFolders.add(new FleetInfo("dir:" + fleetPath, null, null, null));
                for(String statisticalFile : statisticalFolder.list()){
                    treeFolders.add(new FleetInfo("file:" + fleetPath + File.separator + statisticalFile, null, FleetType.file, null));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are adding any old type of Object to your `ArrayList`, do not use generics just do `ArrayList treeFolders`

Comment: One instance of ArrayList has only one type, but I would like to pass different ArrayList to my addStatisticalFiles method

Comment: (answer deleted, I thought it was a C# question. Sorry, please delete this comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As generic is compile time decision , compile will not know what kind of object you are going to insert in list , so its just through error as a part of type safety  when you add object other then T

**Solution 1:** I think generic type T has not much required in your case you can do it with nongeneric  arraylist as method parameter .

**Solution 2 :** you need to cast your object to T as below, but in this case you have to make sure your are passing correct class object which is synch with your Boolean parameter.

```
private  void addStatisticalFiles (String fleetName, ArrayList<T> treeFolders, boolean isFleetInfo){
        String fleetPath = env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH) + fleetName + File.separator + "statistics";
        File statisticalFolder = new File(fleetPath);
        if (statisticalFolder != null && statisticalFolder.exists()){
            if (!isFleetInfo){
                T t =(T)fleetPath;
                treeFolders.add(fleetPath);
                for(String statisticalFile : statisticalFolder.list()){
                    treeFolders.add(fleetPath + File.separator + statisticalFile);
                }
            }else{
              FleetInfo fleetInfo=  new FleetInfo("dir:" + fleetPath, null, null, null);
                T tfleetInfo =(T)fleetInfo;
                treeFolders.add(tfleetInfo );
                for(String statisticalFile : statisticalFolder.list()){
                    treeFolders.add(new FleetInfo("file:" + fleetPath + File.separator + statisticalFile, null, FleetType.file, null));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but add doesn't work: The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type ArrayList<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: then we can go with unsafe arraylist find updated code

Comment: Obviously it works, but I was wondering if it is possible to use a typed array because for example one time I call this function with ArrayList<String>, another time I may use ArrayList<Integer>, but add method gives me error. I don't want an ArrayList with any type of object inside it